# Ricci curvature of sum of metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Is there an estimate for Ric$(g+h)$ in terms of Ric$(g)$ and Ric$(h)$, where $g,h$ are smooth Riemannian metrics?

More specifically can one say that the eigenvalues will decrease (resp. increase) if we take h to be something of constant negative (resp. positive) Ricci?

In the examples I have computed this seems to be the case but I am at a loss of how to prove something in general. If it is helpful I can take the metrics to be K\"ahler?

Comment: Could you please say what types of example you've examined? Particularly, have you tested constant-curvature metrics in one (complex) dimension (which are automatically Kähler)? While I'm asking, could you specify whether you mean the Ricci tensor (a symmetric quadratic form, whose associated $(1, 1)$-form can be computed easily for a Kähler metric) or (since you mention eigenvalues) the Ricci endomorphism (obtained by raising an index of the Ricci tensor)? Thanks. :)

Comment: In one complex dimension I have looked at the ball and considered the hyperbolic, Euclidean and spherical metrics (appropriately restricted). Also in this case I have written down an expression for the sum in terms of conformal factor but I cannot see anything nice I can do with it. In higher dimensions I have considered the ball again and the Bergman metric, Euclidean metric and Fubini-Study metric on it.

Comment: I mean the Ricci tensor here, or in the K\"ahler case the Ricci form associated to the Ricci tensor. It still makes sense to consider eigenvalues here. Although if you understand something about the Ricci endomorphism that could be useful too.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. One natural strategy is to use the formula$$\rho_{g} = -i\partial\bar{\partial} \log \det(g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}})$$for the Ricci form of a Kähler metric. If $G$ and $H$ are positive-definite matrices, then$$G + H = G(G^{-1} + H^{-1})H,$$which leads one to focus on$$-i\partial\bar{\partial} \log \det(G^{-1} + H^{-1}).$$

Comment: Yes I have considered this briefly but a few things are unclear with this approach. First is that whilst one can split the product in the determinant into a product of determinants one cannot do the same for the Hessian of the log (hopefully this makes sense?). Secondly even if we just focus on the suggested expression there is no natural way to proceed as far as I can see. But maybe I am just being blind!

Comment: It is quite possible that there will be no estimate available even in constant curvature cases, but it would be nice to be able to pin down why.

Comment: Since $\log \det(AB) = \log\det A + \log\det B$ and $i\partial\bar{\partial}$ is linear, splitting is okay. :) Offhand, I don't see any way to proceed beyond this either, however, hence the brief comment instead of lengthier analysis....

Comment: @TedShifrin: Just pinging to make sure you've seen this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you provided me with the escape hatch of only focusing on Kahler metrics, I'll immediately jump out that door without even checking if I have a parachute.

There's a little trick to dealing with curvature tensors of sums of metrics that I'm not sure is very well known. I saw it stated as an exercise in Zheng's *Complex differential geometry*. We start by considering a short exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles
$$
0 \to S \to E \to Q \to 0
$$
over a complex manifold of dimension $n$
and recalling the Codazzi-Griffiths equations for the curvatures of the metrics on $S$ and $Q$ induced by a metric on $E$. Then we notice that given a complex manifold $X$ with metrics $h_1$ and $h_2$, there is a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to T_X \to T_X \oplus T_X \to T_X \to 0,
$$
where the first nonzero arrow is $v \mapsto (v,v)$, the second one is $(v,w) \mapsto v-w$, the metric on the direct sum is $h_1 \oplus h_2$, the one on the subbundle is $h_1 + h_2$, and the "quotient" bundle gets the induced metric. Now we just apply Codazzi-Griffiths. (This can be done for any holomorphic vector bundle. Also works in the Riemannian case, actually.)

This yields that the curvature tensor of $h_1+h_2$ is
$$
R(x,\bar y, z, \bar w)
= R_1(x, \bar y, z,\bar w)
+ R_2(x, \bar y, z,\bar w)
- \langle b(x)(z), \overline{b(y)(w)}\rangle_Q,
$$
where $b(x)(z) := (D_{h_1,x} - D_{h_2,x})z$ is the second fundamental form and $h_Q$ is the metric on the "quotient".

To get from this to the Ricci tensor, we're going to integrate two of the tensor elements over the unit sphere with respect to $h_1 + h_2$ (which is the same as taking the trace with respect to them up to a constant factor). The calculations are routine but a bit long, so I'll just say that if we set $m := \min |v|_{h_1}$ and $M := \max |v|_{h_1}$, where $v$ ranges over the unit sphere according to $h_1 + h_2$, then the Ricci tensor of $h_1 + h_2$ is
$$
r(x, \bar y)
= \frac{{M^2}^{2n} - {m^2}^{2n}}{2(n+1)} r_1(x, \bar y)
+ \frac{{(1-m^2)}^{2n} - {(1-M^2)}^{2n}}{2(n+1)} r_2(x, \bar y)
- h_{\operatorname{End}(T_X)}(b(x), \overline{b(y)}),
$$
where $h_{\operatorname{End}(T_X)}$ is the metric we get on $\operatorname{End}(T_X) = \operatorname{Hom}(T_X, T_X)$ by equipping the first factor with $h_1+h_2$ and the second factor with $h_Q$ and calculating the usual Hilbert-Schmidt metric.

You can do essentially the same thing in the Riemannian setting and get something involving more terms with the second fundamental form, see for example [Cavenaghi and Sperança](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14781).

Now, is this helpful? That, uhh, remains to be seen. To be able to answer your question on the eigenvalues you have to be able to estimate the contribution of the metric on the endomorphism bundle. That involves the metric on the "quotient", which can be explicitly calculated (a fun exercise in linear algebra), but honestly I've never been happier after looking at it than I was before.